# Bounded sequence. What's the best constant $c$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence with $x_1=1$, defined by
\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{3x_n^2}
\end{align*}
Prove that there exists a fixed $c>0$ such that $x_n<\sqrt[3]{n+c}$

I cubed the relation in order to prove that $x_n \geq \sqrt[3]{n}$, and I guess that $c$ may be $1$, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: First I tried induction, but failed. Then I tried using a similar approach as for the "$\geq$" part, but I ended up with a sum in the form of 1+1/2+...+1/n, which doesn't converge to any constant.

Comment: As shown in the "possible duplicate", the statement is *wrong*.